Default initialization of tree_sitter::Node
Is there any way to initialize a default value to tree_sitter::Node? So, this is how we parse using tree_sitter.
let mut parser = tree_sitter::Parser::new();
let path = "abc.txt";
let contents = std::fs::read_to_string(&path).unwrap();
let tree : tree_sitter::Tree = parser.parse(contents, None).unwrap();
let cursor : tree_sitter::TreeCursor = &mut tree.walk();

This is fine and we can write an loop to walk over the tree and take actions on the nodes. I was wondering if there is any way to default initialize the Node. I mean declare an global variable or so and fill it later.
Something like:
let mut prev_node : tree_sitter::Node = tree_sitter::Node();

OR
let mut prev_node : tree_sitter::Node = new tree_sitter::Node();


I don't see anything relevant amongst the functions that produce a Node (-> Node), use an Option!
